# Caulk or readjust sink?

Tags: kitchen-sink

We installed an undermount farmhouse sink, and used liquid nails to attach it to the support. That turned out to be a mistake since it’s sitting about 0.25” lower than it should.

The question is: can we just caulk it in place and accept the gap?

If we force it off the liquid nails, is there a straightforward way of doing this? It’s sitting on two wooden supports that it’s glued on to.

Thank you![image][image]

Comment: Why is it sitting lower, did the liquid nails give?

Comment: "Should we" is asking for opinions of which you'll get many but only yours counts and gets closed as off-topic. "Can we" or "How can we remove it", is more objective and could get you a decent answer. See, as written the only possible answer is, "You should leave if you can live with it 1/4" lower than you expected it, but you should remove it if that's unacceptable to you."

Comment: The liquid nails didn’t give. It’s sitting on two very solid brackets, which we glued the sink into using liquid nails.

Comment: Can you raise the support brackets?  How about a picture.  Caulk isn't a good solution for a mistake.

Comment: A) Pictures would be _most_ helpful. B) _All_ the details would be very helpful, too. I (and probably others) assumed you'd glued the whole sink to the counter, knowing that it's just brackets makes a difference. Please share _every_ detail about this installation, even if you don't think it's relevant. C) It's still opinion based - only you can decide if you're willing to live with "caulk in the gap". D) Where is this gap? I'll bet a picture would show us. ;)

Comment: Added photos! The sink is mounted (and glued onto) 1.5 inch wooden supports, and the gap between the countertop and the sink is a 0.25 inches or so.

Answer (score 3):

I may be **wrong**, but undermount sinks should use some kind of mechanical support , like brackets, to hold its weight in place.

Is this an option? Does the sink have any place where you could attach some kind of mechanical support?

The liquid nails stuff is great for ( *as long my expertise goes* ) stuff that does not move, while a sink moves a lot due to weight variation.

And welcome to the Stack o/

Comment: It’s sitting on brackets, we glued it onto them which was a mistake…